# I append to use bootbox.confirm in my directive,but excute wrong

Tags: javascript, angularjs

**HTML:**

```
<a href="#!uploadstatus"><button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" confirm-ng-click="Are you sure">Submit</button></a>
```

angular js is :

```
omapp.directive("confirmNgClick",function(){
    return {
        priority:-1,
        restrict:'A',
        link: function(scope,element,attrs){
        element.bind('click',function(event){

        var message =  attrs.confirmNgClick || "Are you sure?";
        if (message && !confirm(message)){
             event.stopImmediatePropagation();
             event.preventDefault();
        } //if
        }) // bind
        }//function
    }
})
```

When I click the button, it raises a confirm box. When I click "yes", the page go to next page. Everything is fine. I want to make confirm box beautiful, so 'm using bootbox.

I have changed the angularjs directive as below :

```
omapp.directive("confirmNgClick",function(){
    return {
        priority:-1,
        restrict:'A',
        link: function(scope,element,attrs){
        element.bind('click',function(event){
        var message =  attrs.confirmNgClick || "Are you sure?";
        bootbox.confirm(message,function(result){
            if (! result){
                event.stopImmediatePropagation();
                event.preventDefault();
            }

        })

        }) // bind
        }//function
    }
})
```

It is going wrong. How can I do ?

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0):

```
omapp.directive("confirmNgClick",function(httpPostFactory,$ngBootbox,$location){
    return {
        priority:-1,
        restrict:'A',
        link: function(scope,element,attrs){
        element.bind('click',function(event){
        var message =  attrs.confirmNgClick || "Are you sure?";
        event.stopImmediatePropagation();
        event.preventDefault();
        bootbox.confirm(message,function(result,$location){
            if (result){
                window.location.href = '#!/uploadstatus';
            }
        })
        }) // bind
        }//function
    }
})
```

The code above is ok